# AngularJS $scope dropping

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am hoping someone can help me understand an annoying problem I am having with `$scope` in AngularJS. Please see the comments in my code below:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;

    $http.get("http://server/api/Blah/GetData/" + $scope.id).success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        alert($scope.data.MyObject.Property); //displays the expected value. - Not Undefined or null
    }).error(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            var d = document.getElementById("iframe");

            d.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = $scope.data.MyObject.Property; //Now MyObject is magically undefined.           

        }, 0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the timing of how your code get executed.

This is fixed code with some logging:
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;

```
console.log(1);

var promise = $http.get("http://server/api/Blah/GetData/" + $scope.id).success(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log(2);
    alert($scope.data.MyObject.Property); //displays the expected value. - Not Undefined or null
}).error(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        var d = document.getElementById("iframe");

        console.log(3);
        // d.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = $scope.data.MyObject.Property;

        promise.then(function () {
            console.log(4);
            d.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = $scope.data.MyObject.Property;
        });

    }, 0);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

$http.get returns a promise and your success function is not run until that promise is resolved by the http call. This is asynchronous and takes a while to happen because the code calls the server.

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded' is called when the view content is loaded, seeing that you cannot predict what order these will fire in but this is likely to happen before your http call has finished so the data property hasn't been set yet.

Your controller should have no concept of the DOM so you should not be calling document.getElementById in there anyway. If you have a binding in your view it will update with the scope. Put {{data.MyObject.Property}} in your view and when your success callback function updates the scope it will magically appear in the views binding. This is how you should be doing things in Angular.